# My app crash if I use findViewById in other class than MainActivity

Tags: android

I need to use the method setText() to write text in a TextView.
If i write this

```
TextView t = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.test);
```

in my MainActivity class it works, if i try writing it in another class, for example here

```
public class AssociaCarta extends Activity{
    public void associaCarta(int numeroRandom, ImageView carta) {   
        TextView t = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.test);
    }
}
```

my app crashes.
I don't understand why.

Comment: Where's your logcat? Does it print out anything?

Comment: Did you declare the other activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: `test` needs to be in the View that you inflate when you call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. If there's no `TextView` with the ID `test` in that View, then you're going to get a null.

Comment: You need to provide the exception that occurs when you app crashes. When are you calling `associaCarta()`? Are you sure the activities view has already been initialized at that point?

Comment: @Matteo Depasquali what the name of layout of MainActivity and AssociaCarta activity...for more detail please give your code..

Comment: I made a big mistake. I tried to reach a textView included in the xml of MainActivity.class from AssociaCarta.class 
What should i do to use the method setText() in AssociaCarta.class to write in a TextView included in the xml of MainActivity.class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be to pass the current Activity as a parameter to your method, something like this:

```
public class AssociaCarta {
    public void associaCarta(Activity context, int numeroRandom, ImageView carta) {
        TextView t = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.user);
    }
}
```

Then you would use it in your MainActivity like this:

```
AssociaCarta carta = new AssociaCarta();
carta.associaCarta(this, randomNumber, cartaImageView);
```